# How to test branch.io links using iOS simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, deep-linking, branch.io

Hi is there a way to test branch.io deep links in iOS Simulator. We need to make sure it works on different devices, as we have a report in production that something fails on iPhone 7 and need to debug it as it works on iPhone 6/6SPlus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex from Branch.io here:

Universal Links work in the simulator the same way as on a physical device for iOS 10. They do not work at all in iOS 9 simulators.

As long as you're using a simulator with iOS, you can test them as usual. The Messages app is a good option for this.

Comment: This is not the case for me. When I paste it in the Messages app then open it, it opens in Safari with an initial popup saying "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid". You can share how you configured your deep link? Maybe I am missing something that's optional for creating the link, but necessary for it perform properly in this situation. The app I'm using is being run on a iPhone 6 simulator with iOS 11.0

Comment: @PatNeedham I just re-confirmed that Universal Links work in the simulator with iOS 11, so it sounds like a potential problem with your Universal Links configuration itself. I'd check out our [troubleshooting guide](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#troubleshooting-universal-links) for next steps!

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I read more of the docs and found I was missing `[Branch setUseTestBranchKey:YES];` before calling `Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];`. After adding that and re-installing, thee built-in event for PURCHASE (only built-in I'm using) now shows up under Quick Links tab in the dashboard for the link, but none of the custom events do, even though they are still being logged under Liveview -> Events

Comment: I'd suggest writing in to the Branch [integrations team](https://support.branch.io/support/tickets/new) so they can help get everything sorted out!

Answer (score 1):

Following are 2 reasons that a simulator is not fit for testing deep links.

1. The simulator does not support Universal Links
2. There is no App Store on the simulator, that is why You can not see true redirect behavior

Answer (score 1):

Works for iOS Simulator but version above 10.

Paste the link in Messages app

Click the link it will redirect you to Application.